# How to query DynamoDB table by hash using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with the following key [customerid (HASH), sku (RANGE)].

I'm trying to query by customerid only. I'm currently getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:545) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

I've added the queryLookupStrategy to my application in the hopes it worked. Tried the several values, but the message remains.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(queryLookupStrategy = QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
public class ProductItemApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductItemApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is that possible? Or is it a limitation of Dynamo? Since Cassandra can easily do this, I'm assuming Dynamo would be able to do it too, but may be wrong.

Would I need to define an index with only customerid to query this? If so, what's the best way to do that in code with spring-data?

Or is this a limitation of spring data with dynamo, and to achieve this I'd need to use the dynamo client explicitly rather than spring data?

My repository is defined as such:

```
interface CustomerItemRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomerItem, CustomerItemId> {
    List<CustomerItem> findByCustomerId(String customerId);
}
```

And my key is:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerItemId {
    private String customerId;
    private String sku;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "customerId")
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "sku")
    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }
}
```

Finally, my item is:

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "CustomerItem")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class CustomerItem {
        @Id
        private CustomerItemId id;

//... a few other non key fields...

        CustomerItem(String customerId, String sku) {
            this.id = new CustomerItemId(customerId, sku);
        }

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "customerId")
        public String getCustomerId() {
            return id.getCustomerId();
        }

        @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "sku")
        public String getSku() {
            return id.getSku();
        }

        public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
            this.id = new CustomerItemId(customerId, id != null ? id.getSku() : null);
        }

        public void setSku(String sku) {
            this.id = new CustomerItemId(id != null ? id.getCustomerId() : null, sku);
        }
    }
```

What's the most elegant way to solve this? Dynamo seemed the right tech to store this kind of simple data cheaply, but now I'm thinking I may be better off using something else.

Comment: I know this does not address your question, but for a Java project I would use DynamoDBMapper for object persistence, not Spring. DynamoDBMapper is excellent.

Comment: I actually tried to use DynamoDBMapper instead and it just works free of hassle, so I'll use that instead. Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, glad you found it useful. I have added an answer.

Comment: The [derjust/spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb) implementation actually uses the `DynamoDbMapper`, which is why the AWS annotations are used on your entities. It most certainly *is* possible to query by just the hash key - we do this in many places using this library. If you can provide a full sample project, with exact versions and all dependencies, etc, I might be able find out what's not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this does not address your question, but for a Java project I would use DynamoDBMapper for object persistence, not Spring. It provides a really clean way to map your plain objects into DynamoDB and is provided and supported by AWS. I've used it a lot and DynamoDBMapper is excellent.

Comment: Yes, it does not have the "bug" (?) spring seems to have when querying only by hash, and writing a generic class to handle dynamodb accesses pretty much offers the same level of abstraction Spring would, so definitely works for me. Just forces you to write a few more tests, but I can live with that.